# How to hide the showing videos Youtube player api android

Tags: android, youtube-api

I had implemented youtube player api in my app but after playing each videos it is showing other related videos how can I hide it

Comment: I don't think there is any way . I checked it way back and couldn't find any solution . Not sure if there is any new solution .

Comment: is it sure bro?

Comment: I am not 100% sure , I could not find any solution . I cannot say for sure that there is no solution .